# close pooled connections to mysql from mysql.connector python

Tags: python, connection-pooling, mysql-connector

I am using mysql-connector package and doing connection pooling using `MySQLConnectionPool` class.
I have a long running process.While running this process all pooled connections remains idle in irregular pattern of time-period.

In source code there is `_remove_connections()` method to close all connections.

But is there any way to check regularly for idle connections in a pool and close them after some period of inactivity and reconnect them as needed?

Comment: do you need connection pooling ? if not you can disable it. Also can you provide package which you're using ? is it native or odbc

Comment: I need pooling.Python package is mysql-connector.

Comment: No connection monitoring can not be done developer has to call close() so that such released connections are moved to pool and upon longer inactivity removed.

Comment: **upon longer inactivity removed** how? does mysql-connector does it or not? how much seconds count as inactivity?

Comment: It depends on the value you have configured, usually recommended value is 30 seconds and if you do not configure it then it is 0 which is infinite. If it is non zero then driver takes care of it.

Comment: how to configure that value in python package?